# Select a List inside a List and add an item to it for JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am trying to make a JSON where there are multiple addresses and each address has its own multiple contacts. For that matter I made a class as:

```
public class Supplier
{
    public decimal N100 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> N101 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> N102 { get; set; }
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> D1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> D2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> D3 { get; set; }

    public List<SMFAdd> contacts = new List<SMFAdd>();
}

public class SupplierRoot
{
    public List<Supplier> address = new List<Supplier>();
}
```

where SMFAdd is another class.

I can add addresses in the list as:

```
Models.SupplierRoot s = new Models.SupplierRoot();
s.address.Add(sd); // where sd is the return output from database.
```

but when I try to add the respective contacts to the address as:

```
s.address.Select(x => x.contacts.Add(sd));
```

The compiler gave the following error

> Type argument method cannot be inferred from the usage

How can I make it working? I want to make a JSON as:

```
{
  "address": {
    "contacts": [
      {
        "N100": 6.0,
        "N101": 7.0,
        "N102": 2.0,
        "S1": "Ghulam",
        "S2": "Suppliers",
        "S3": "Sales",
        "D1": null,
        "D2": null,
        "D3": null,
      },
      {
        "N100": 7.0,
        "N101": 7.0,
        "N102": null,
        "S1": "07",
        "S2": null,
        "S3": null,
        "D1": null,
        "D2": null,
        "D3": null,
      },
      {
        "N100": 8.0,
        "N101": 7.0,
        "N102": null,
        "S1": "1010",
        "S2": null,
        "S3": null,
        "D1": null,
        "D2": null,
        "D3": null,
      }
    ],
    "N100": 0.0,
    "N101": null,
    "N102": null,
    "S1": "Main Market",
    "S2": "ISB",
    "S3": null,
    "D1": null,
    "D2": null,
    "D3": null,
  },
  "address": {
    "contacts": [
      {
        "N100": 6.0,
        "N101": 7.0,
        "N102": 2.0,
        "S1": "Ghulam",
        "S2": "Suppliers",
        "S3": "Sales",
        "D1": null,
        "D2": null,
        "D3": null,
      },
      {
        "N100": 7.0,
        "N101": 7.0,
        "N102": null,
        "S1": "07",
        "S2": null,
        "S3": null,
        "D1": null,
        "D2": null,
        "D3": null,
      },
      {
        "N100": 8.0,
        "N101": 7.0,
        "N102": null,
        "S1": "1010",
        "S2": null,
        "S3": null,
        "D1": null,
        "D2": null,
        "D3": null,
      }
    ],
    "N100": 0.0,
    "N101": null,
    "N102": null,
    "S1": "Main Market",
    "S2": "ISB",
    "S3": null,
    "D1": null,
    "D2": null,
    "D3": null,
  }
}
```

Comment: s.address.Select(x => x.contacts.Add(sd));  - Select is used for selecting items with a specified condition and you're trying to add items.

Comment: yes, but how can I access that list? How to make that JSON?

Comment: If you need to add something for each element in list, you can use a foreach loop or list.ForEach() method. However, to get JSON, you need to serialize objects

Comment: but using foreach will add a same contact to all addresses... Is there any way to use Where() with Foreach()??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add the item in Contacts through Select operation which is used to select the item. You can use ForEach to iterate over each address and add the item in contact list.

**To add the address in each contact**

```
s.address.Foreach(x => x.contacts.Add(sd));
```

**Now to convert to Json**

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s)
```

For JsonConvert you need to have a reference of *newtonsoft* package.

Comment: but using foreach will add a same contact to all addresses... Is there any way to use Where() with Foreach()??

Comment: You can put the Where to filter those records where item need to be added so `s.address.Where(x => your condition).ToList().Foreach(x => x.contacts.Add(sd)); `

Answer (score 0):

For working with json you could use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (Newtonsoft) it is a very simple to use framework. After including `Newtonsoft.Json` you can serialize objects like this:

```
var myObject = WhatEverObject();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
```

and if you want to deserialize your json string:

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WhatEverObject>(json);
```

And to add the addresses:

```
s.address.Foreach(x => x.contacts.Add(sd));
```

Comment: but using foreach will add a same contact to all addresses... Is there any way to use Where() with Foreach()??

Answer (score 0):

What I can infer here is "sd" has address and list of contact . The structure of SMFAdd and Supplier is different. Supplier has a list of contacts and SMFAdd has everything as Supplier except Contact list. Hence there is a conflict in the strucure you are trying to add to the list. Hence the error.

Simply

address.add(sd) and address.contact.add(sd) is different because contact doesn't contain a list of contacts again but address do